# VB.NET Make Windows shortcuts to different forms in VB.NET program

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a VB.NET program that has multiple forms that need to be loaded when a shortcut with a certain command line parameter is in the shortcut.

Is this possible by creating a command line argument and how?

For example:
When program.exe is loaded Form1 is loaded
When "program.exe" -form2 is loaded Form2 is shown instead of Form1.

Would I also be able to link to these in the "Shell" code in other VB programs as this program stores all of the "about" windows for a suite of programs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the command lines with the StartUp Event found in the MyApplication Class

Example:

```
    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        If e.CommandLine.Contains("-form2") Then
            'Load Form2
        ElseIf e.CommandLine.Contains("-form3") Then
            'Load Form3
        Else
            'Load Form 1
        End If
    End Sub
```